# Forcing all controls on MVC2 form to validate using JQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a way (using JQuery or Java Script) to force an MVC2 form to perform validation on it's fields with Data Annotation validation without posting back to the server?

I have a MVC2 form that is quite complex. Many of the fields are hidden or displayed depending on other selections. Given this, some of the fields are validated using Data Annotations and some are validated using custom JQuery.

In the case that one of the fields with custom validation fails it's validation I wish to prevent the form from posting back however this stops any of the fields with Data Annotation Validation from working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO mixing `jquery validate` with `MSAjax` is a bad thing. For complex forms with many custom validation rules I would recommend using only jquery validate and on the server a more powerful validation framework than DataAnnotations such as [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) which [works nicely with ASP.NET MVC](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation).